# Nesting all images one directory deeper with htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to get any content with the jpeg | gif | png | pdf extension to redirect from
/wp-content/uploads/* to /subdirectory/wp-content/uploads/*

I'm using this rule:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/.*?/[^.]+\.(jpg|gif|png|pdf))$ /subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```

I think I'm doing something wrong with the extensions.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to make the inner parentheses a non-capturing group using the `?:` immidiately after the opening parenthesis for the file extensions so that `$1` references the outer capture group:

```
RewriteRule ^(wp-content/uploads/[^.]+\.(?:jpg|gif|png|pdf)) subdirectory/$1 [L,NC]
```